# Can AppEngine response count metric be grouped on response class?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

I'm trying to create an alert on CGP/stackdriver using the http/server/response_count [metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-appengine) for app engine. This metric has an response_code field that I can group_by:

```
fetch gae_app::appengine.googleapis.com/http/server/response_count
| filter metric.response_code>=500 && metric.response_code<600
| every 10m
| group_by [metric.response_code], sum(val())
```

But say I want to merge all 500+ responses under a 5xx class of response and then aggregate to a single count for the range, is it possible to pre-process so the group_by in the above example yields a single time series eg 5xx? I notice that one of the load balancer metrics has a "response_code_class" of this kind, but this is NOT available for this metric.

After that I'm looking for a ratio of 5xx requests to all requests, would that even be possible with this metric?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a query that does the following:

- Use a `group_by` to count the 5xx responses in a 10-minute sliding window.
- In the same `group_by`, also count all responses in the same 10-minute sliding window.
- After the `group_by`, simply compute the ratio of the two counts.

```
fetch gae_app
| metric 'appengine.googleapis.com/http/server/response_count'
| group_by [], sliding(10m), [
    countAll: sum(response_count), 
    count5xx: sum(if(response_code>=500 && response_code < 600, response_count, 0))]
| value (count5xx / countAll)
| every 1m
```

Screenshot of the chart produced by a similar query:

[image: Screenshot of the chart produced by a similar query]

The output of the above query is a ratio of 5xx responses to all responses.

Note: if you wanted to compute these ratios, for example, by `zone`, simply add `zone` to the first argument of `group_by` like this: `group_by [zone], sliding(10m), [countAll: ..., count5xx: ...] | value (count5xx / countAll)`

Comment: This looks promising, I'm going to try it out

Answer (score 0):

There's  another way to compute the ratio of error responses to all responses. In this case, because the numerator and denominator for the ratio are derived from the same time series, you can also compute the ratio by grouping. Please check the grouping query format once:

```
fetch gae_app::appengine.googleapis.com/http/server/response_count
| group_by [metric.response_code],
    sum(if(response_code_class = 500, val(), 0)) / sum(val())
```

For more details please refer to example [grouping](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-group-ratio).

Comment: This is taken for the manual and I tried it but it doesn't work for my metric. There is no response class as I say in my description, this example does not work. I'll modify my description to say response_code_class and make it clearer.

Comment: Have you check the format of your query. I have suggested that response_code_class only

Comment: Please do let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: response_code_class is NOT available for this metric, your answer does not work, this is not a question about a load-balancing metric

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding in that you can add "app engine" in place of "load balancing". I edited my answer too. Once check and let me know.